# "error": "Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined"

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, findoneandupdate

**Hello everybody !!**
Here I have a big problem, I would like to do a registration in back with Node.js sequelize and mySql.
I looked here and there but I did not find the answer to my problem so I came to ask you for help.
With mongoDb, it was easier but I admit that I am going in circles.

Here is my code:

```js
// Importation :

// Bcrypt:
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

// Jsonwebtoken d'authentification:
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

// Import du models user:
const models = require("../models/user")

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Fonction/

// Incription:
exports.signup = (req, res) => {

  const username  = req.body.username;
  const email     = req.body.email;
  const password  = req.body.password;
  const bio       = req.body.bio;
  const admin     = req.body.admin;

  console.log(req.body)
  try {

    models.User.findOne({
      attributes: ['email'],
      where: {
        email: email
      }
    })

    .then((userFound => {
      if (!userFound) {

        bcrypt.hash(password, 10, function (err, bcryptPassword) {

          const newUser = models.User.create({
            username  : username,
            email     : email,
            password  : bcryptPassword,
            bio       : bio,
            admin     : false
            })

            .then(newUser => {
              res.status(201).json({
                'userId': newUser.id
              })
            })
            .catch(err => {
              res.status(500).json({
                'error': 'Impossible d\'ajouter un utilisateur'
              })
            })

          })

        } else {
          return res.status(409).json({
            error: 'Ce compte existe déjà '
          })
        }

      })
      .catch((err) =>
        res.status(500).json({
          'err': err + 'Impossible de vérifier l\'utilisateur',
        })
      )

      )
  }catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      error: error.message
    });
  }

}
```

[image: response from Postman's console]

And the model User:

```js
'use strict'
const { db } = require('../config/connexion')

const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')

const user = db.define('User', {
  // Model attributes are defined here
  username: DataTypes.STRING,
  email: DataTypes.STRING,
  password: DataTypes.STRING,
  bio: DataTypes.TEXT,
  admin: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
})

module.exports = user
```

and connexion.js:

```js
// Connexion de sequelize à mysql:
const {
  Sequelize
} = require('sequelize')

const db = new Sequelize(
  process.env.NAMEDB,
  process.env.USERDB,
  process.env.PASSWORDDB, {
    host: process.env.HOSTDB,
    dialect: process.env.DIALECTDB,
    pool: {
      min: 0, //  nombre minimum de connexion dans le pool
      max: 5, //  nombre maximum de connexion dans le pool
      acquire: 30000, //  durée maximale, en millisecondes, pendant laquelle ce pool essaiera d'obtenir la connexion avant de lancer une erreur
      idle: 10000, //  temps maximum, en millisecondes, pendant lequel une connexion peut être inactive avant d'être libérée
    },
  }
)

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Etablit la connexion à mysql:
const dbConnect = async (db) => {
  await db
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
      db.sync()
      console.log('Connecté à la base de données MySQL!')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('error: ' + err.message)
      setTimeout(() => {
        dbConnection(db)
      }, 5000)
    })
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Exportation:
module.exports = {
  db,
  dbConnect,
}
```

Certainly there is still a lot to do, but being a beginner I improve as I go.

Do not be angry with me if my English is not at the top, I admit that it is not my strong point.

Thanking you in advance for all the help provided.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. A picture can be worth a thousand words but they are worth significantly less than that on Stackoverflow. Please have a read of this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048425)

Comment: @ GarethDah, actually as much for me I correct it afterwards

Comment: Could you please check module.exports of models module? Maybe User is missing...

Comment: @Kemal Kaplan, I added the model user, sorry;)

Comment: I think we also need to see the connexion file, o/w we need sequelize.define instead of db.define...

Comment: Try models.findOne instead of models.User.findOne

Comment: @KemalKaplan, I just added it if you need another file, tell me;)

Comment: @TusharShahi, I just tried I still have the same error :(

Comment: Hm, `console.log(models)` before this statement `models.User.findOne({`

Comment: @TusharShahi, the console returns me:
User

Comment: Suggest you to add new info to the question too. And what does `User` mean, just a string?

Comment: @TusharShahi, as I said to lejlun, I didn't change the second models.user so that's why it didn't work, head in the air that I am ... But now postman turns me around:  "error": "(intermediate value).catch is not a function"

Comment: Thanks to @everyone for helping out, now postman returns to me:
 "error": "(intermediate value) .catch is not a function"
I don't know what wrestling he's talking to me about and even less why

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone for your help!
I solved my second problem by removing the penultimate catch.
Thanks again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the `user` variable to be the export of the file

```js
module.exports = user
```

You then import the `user` variable as `models`.

```js
const models = require("../models/user")
```

**this means that you do not need to access `user` as a property. Instead use:**

```js
models.findOne({ // Changed from models.User to models
    attributes: ["email"],
    where: {
        email: email,
    },
});
```

This should stop your current error, but you will keep on getting errors until you change all instances of `models.User` to `models`.

**Your main file should end up looking like this:**

```js
// Importation :

// Bcrypt:
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

// Jsonwebtoken d'authentification:
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

// Import du models user:
const models = require("../models/user");

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Fonction/

// Incription:
exports.signup = (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const bio = req.body.bio;
  const admin = req.body.admin;

  console.log(req.body);
  try {
    models
      .findOne({
        attributes: ["email"],
        where: {
          email: email,
        },
      })

      .then(
        ((userFound) => {
          if (!userFound) {
            bcrypt.hash(password, 10, function (err, bcryptPassword) {
              const newUser = models
                .create({
                  username: username,
                  email: email,
                  password: bcryptPassword,
                  bio: bio,
                  admin: false,
                })

                .then((newUser) => {
                  res.status(201).json({
                    userId: newUser.id,
                  });
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                  res.status(500).json({
                    error: "Impossible d'ajouter un utilisateur",
                  });
                });
            });
          } else {
            return res.status(409).json({
              error: "Ce compte existe déjà ",
            });
          }
        }).catch((err) =>
          res.status(500).json({
            err: err + "Impossible de vérifier l'utilisateur",
          })
        )
      );
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you indeed I have just corrected the 2 models.user and it returns me this error more .. Mias instead postman returns this one to me:
 "error": "(intermediate value) .catch is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

You are directly setting the export object equal to the user object.

When you do this `const models = require("../models/user")`, `models` is equal to the `user` value directly.

You can directly use `models.findOne`. Read [this](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/)

Answer (score 0):

Check your "model" file to see if the "User" model exists there. Also check if you are using the 'module.exports'

Comment: I just added the model user in my post, I forgot to send it with ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting the `User` model directly, but calling it like it is in an object property named `User`. You can either access it directly, changing:

```
models.User.findOne
```

to:

```
models.findOne
```

and then you'd probably want to rename `models` to `User`.

**Or** change your export to:

```
module.exports = { User: user };
```